# how to enter text in UITextfield multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i know this question is too simple ,i have sendEmailButton once i click the button a new UIView will appear and it has UITextField and UITextView after entering texts in UITextField and in UITextView ,i click submit button the details will be send to a email , when i click sendEmailButton once again an empty UITextField n UITextView should appear

Answer (score 1):

Once you click submit, Clear the contents of UITextField and UITextView.. 
you can just set the text property of both views to empty string

textField.text = @"";
textView.text = @"";

Comment: can i write textfield.text=@""; in the beginning itself , can i write nil alternative to @"" ?